# Can you use multiple instances of Edge on a Selenium Grid Node?

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-grid

Using the config below, I am only seeing one instance of Edge running on my node.

When using chrome with a similar setup, I can run multiple browsers on the same node.

Here is the config.json I am using:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
          "maxInstances": 4
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 7777,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": 192.168.56.101
  }
}
```

I am running  the hub and node on a single VM running

- Win10 Aniversery Edition
- the corresponding Edge WebDriver (14393)
- Selenium 2.53.1 selenium-server-standalone.jar.
- Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

As per MS (https://twitter.com/instylevii/status/783480823445987329), at this time **the MS Edge WebDriver support only one session per Selenium Grid node**.

Comment: As a workaround you can pack one Edge to Docker image: https://medium.com/@aandryashin/selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution-f5a7eab205ad

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can exploit Windows virtual desktop basic feature.

See [headless-selenium-for-win](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win)

I've used and validated it on a Windows 2012 server with 5 concurrent IE11 instances.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I am concerned from the issues that the author is not supporting it well, and it seems to have some pretty grim bugs (e.g. the minimization issue).  How confident would you be running this on a grid VM farm?

Comment: About the specific bug you are talking about, it does not matter at all in a dedicated grid VM farm, isn't it ?
I've just parse all the open issues, and I don't see any blocker.
I mean sometime bug reporter did not reply to questions, or sometime, it's a matter of user/user session/open graphical session.
So, either you test it in your farm until you check it suits your need, or you can improve the "headless-selenium-for-win" source code that is available in GNU General Public License v3.0.